# add a UIView above tableView and start scrolling when UIView is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

Hello (first sorry for my english), I have a `UIView` above a `UITableView`, and `UIView` is hidden when I start scrolling in the `UITableView`.

The problem I'm facing that the `UITableView` push the `UIView` to the top and in the same time is scrolling. I want to start the scrolling the time when the `UIView` is hidden.

if you see in the gif below the row 0, row 1 and row 2 are hidden before the `UIView`.

[image]

> What I'm looking for, if you see the sentence **Swipe Right from left ...** is stay in the same height until the `UIView` is hidden. (this Configurator is from Flexbile Header **Material.io**)

[image]

**This is my code :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {

lazy var redView: UIView = {
   let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200))
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()

lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 100))

    return tableView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(redView)
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "row \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if(offset > 200){
        self.redView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 0)
    }else{

        self.redView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 200 - offset)

    }

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.redView.frame.maxY, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height:(self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.redView.frame.maxY)))
    tableView.frame = rect
}




}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {

  lazy var redView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200))
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
  }()

  lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

    return tableView
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(redView)
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(200, 0, 0, 0)

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "row \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
  }

  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if(offset > 200){
      self.redView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 0)
    }else{

      self.redView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 200 - offset)

    }
  }
}
```

Learn more at this link https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/how-to-create-a-stretchable-tableviewheader-in-ios-ee9ed049aba3

Comment: this makes the redview not clickable :(

Comment: you will need to add tableview first then the redView